# 3rd party dll raising events

Tags: c#

I use a third party dll to get some data from their servers. There is a void method that I call and then i subscribe to an event raised by the call to this method. The event raised returns the data through its parameters.

so,
call to : void getdata(id)
raises:  void onReturn(object)  --> which returns an object that has the data.

This WORKS everytime when there is a single call to getdata(id)

The problem is when i loop through the list of ids, and inside that loop call getdata(id) for that list, the corresponding events are not raised properly.
Say for a list of 10 ids, there are 10 calls to getdata(id) but only few onReturns are raised.

The returned object also returns the id that was passed to getdata(id) so I can match the data i sent and the data that i receive.

Is there a way to make sure that all events get listened to? So if I send 10 ids by getdata(id), I want to make sure that the 10 onReturns are processed.

And i'm using c#, .net 4.0

Thanks

Comment: Are you registering for the return event or is there a delegate you pass as the callback?

Comment: registering for the return event.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a third party DLL, there's no telling how they've implemented it.  When you step through in Debug mode, do you get past the call to `getData()` before the `onReturn()` listener is called?  If so, it might be using threads (or at least asynchronous listeners) internally, and calling multiple `getData()`s too close together might cause it to stomp on pending responses.

The only way I could think to try and get around this is to use multithreading yourself, e.g. with a Mutex that waits after the call to `getData()` and releases in the `onReturn()` event.  This way you'd only have one outstanding request at a time, which seems to be the condition that works for you.

Edit:  Have you talked to the third party vendor about this yet?  I'm guessing their support isn't the best if you thought of us first, but it might be worth a shot.

Edit the second:  When you say it gets data from their servers, does this mean it makes requests over the network?  If those requests aren't encrypted, perhaps you could reverse engineer the protocol and make a new API for yourself instead of relying on a proven buggy black box.

Comment: +1, agreed about the likelihood that this is an event raised on a worker thread.  Doesn't make much sense to have getdata() not just return the data otherwise.  And yes, get support from the vendor.

Comment: Its an old dll and they don't support it anymore. But we still use it. I will give your solution a try.
Thanks for your feedback appreciate it.